# PhpMyAdmin Configuration Storage => Multi-User / Server => still not working

Tags: configuration, phpmyadmin, storage

my pma-installation is on one server(main-server).

On another server(client 1) i have the following:

my pma-database: phpmyadmin
my user with all privileges to that database: test_pma
my second user: mike

The user "mike" is just a normal mysql-user with one database and no privileges to the database "phpmyadmin".

My config.inc.php:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Main Server';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/test/core/mysql.sock';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/*Client Server 1...*/
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Client 1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'IP-ADRESS'; // Just placeholder! In my config is the real IP!
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

// And then in a loop for every server...
...
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
...
```

The database exists and the tables too.

I tried to set the "controluser" with the following:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'test_pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'test_pma';
```

and also with:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['control_user'] = 'test_pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['control_pass'] = 'test_pma';
```

but it is always the same problem.
If i log in to pma as the normal user "mike", i get the known warning about the configuration storage.

As the full privileged user "test_pma" all is fine.

Can someone tell me what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Damn what a jungle...

in my attempts i also cleared cookies and website-data, but with the same result.

Now i cleared cookies and website-data again and... it works!

The only difference:
First time deleting cookies and website-data, in my config.inc.php i used "control_user / control_pass".
But this time "controluser / controlpass".

Seems that in my attempts with "controluser / controlpass" i only logged out and logged in again, but not cleared cookies and website-data.

Why just logging in again wasn't enough? I don't know...

And regarding the "control_*" i thought it would be ok (according to the [docs](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_control_*)).
Maybe i misunderstood...